# Need to run a separate power shell script using nodejs inside my Ubuntu OS

Tags: node.js, powershell

Need to run a separate power shell script using nodejs in my Ubuntu OS

var spawn = require("child_process").spawn,child;
child = spawn("powershell.exe",["file path"]);

```
Error: spawn powershell.exe ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
(internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
    at Function.Module.runMain 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
(internal/child_process.js:246:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
```

Comment: Can you share your code please ?

Comment: Did you install Powershell on your platform ?

Comment: `powershell.exe` is not the command name for PowerShell on Ubuntu. It is `pwsh`.